# MacTex installation on MacBook pro w/ OSX 10.9.5

Tags: installing, mactex, mac

After a OSX system reinstallation from scratch, I try to reinstall also MacTex.

The new installation stops at the initial stage of *package verification* with the error:

```
WindowServer[112]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to
Installer, psn 0x0-0x246246, securitySessionID=0x186a4, err=-13066
```

I already repaired the disk permissions, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

Fabrizio